# ANDROID Installation issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2mkZ.png)Getting error mentioned in screenshot while installing the app in ubuntu OS.

> error is: "Gradle 'TestForError' project refresh failed >
>   Error:Process 'command
>   '/home/vignesh08/Downloads/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 2"

[image]

Comment: Please post your build.gradle file also.

Comment: It will be helpful if you share log of Gradle console

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
}
```

to your build.gradle.
Then clean and rebuild your project and then run it.